# html display inline property and make two check box in the same row

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie to Html and currently I have some problem playing around with `display` style:

I would like to create two checkbox in the same line with one label in front of each, however, with the following syntax, my checkbox will always go vertical (one on top of the other).

```
<div>
    <label></label>
    <div><input type='checkbox'></div>
    <label></label>
    <div><input type='checkbox'></div>
</div>
```

I understand that there display:inline can solve this problem. But as you can see, in the following code, I have several `<div>` element, I tried to add `display:inline` into all the elements in the outer `<div>`, but it is not working. I am not entirely sure what is going wrong. Maybe I miss something ?

The other thing is that what if I want to make them both in the same line and also float to the left, should I just add a float:left to each elements in the outer `<div>`? It seems very inefficient since there maybe quite a lot elements in the outer `<div>`.

Any help or hint will be appreciated ~

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap your inputs into div's, you will get line breaks. Get rid of them. Like this for example:

```
<div>
    <label>First</label>
    <input type='checkbox'>
    <label>Second</label>
    <input type='checkbox'>
</div>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/froweotm/)

Comment: `input` elements can be placed within the `label` elements. If you're to leave them outside, you should always give your `input` elements appropriate `id` attributes which can be referenced in `for` attributes assigned to your `label` elements.

Comment: Good catch! My example is very minimalistic and bad from a accessibility point of view. But it shows the culprit in the given code of OP.

Answer (score 2):

What you say you've tried should be working. Here is a basic demo:

```css
div * {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label></label>
    <div><input type='checkbox'></div>
    <label></label>
    <div><input type='checkbox'></div>
</div>
```

I imagine what's happening is that your parent `div` style is also being applied to your inner `div` elements, overriding the inline style declaration. Ensure that your inner `div` element selectors have higher specificity than your parent one.

An easy solution is to simply give your parent `div` element a `class` attribute and style on that:

```
<div class="parent">
    ....
```

```css
.parent {
    /* Parent style. */
}

.parent div {
    display: inline;
    /* Child style. */
}
```

---

Depending on what you're trying to achieve though, a better solution may just be to place your `input` elements *inside* your `label` elements:

```
<label>
    My label text
    <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

#### Example

```html
<label>
  My first label text
  <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
<label>
  My second label text
  <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

With this approach you can click on the label text to toggle the checkboxes.

Comment: If you can change the html, don't do this. If your html is fixed, this might be your solution, but overriding all `div *` is very dangerous.

Comment: @Alp any particular reason why you're suggesting not to do this? If you want your checkbox to be in the middle of a big red box, separate from the label, a `div` seems pretty fitting to me. Perhaps a `span` would be more friendly.

Comment: the `div`s surrounding the `input` elements are unnecessary markup. Using them and overriding their default behaviour introduces unneeded complexity.

Comment: @Alp how can you possibly know they're unnecessary? OP hasn't clarified what they're wanting to do with them.

Comment: As long as we don't get more context i assume that the minimal version is sufficient. I like your second version though.